# How do you get Eclipse's built-in diff tool to ignore differences in whitespace?

Tags: svn, eclipse, diff

I'm working on a large codebase that's been touched by many hands.  As I work through bugs, I've been converting the source to be more readable which involves a lot of minor changes in indentation depth.  Unfortunately this makes all the changes that pertain to a bugfix completely hidden in the mess when Eclipse declares every single line to be different in a file.

Is there some way to make Eclipse [ignore the whitespace](https://github.com/blog/967-github-secrets) when you review a diff?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Eclipse, go to **Window** > **Preferences**.

Then search for "**patch**" and click on **General** > **Compare/Patch**.

Check *Ignore white space*.

Now only the details that matter in the diff will show up.