# In Eclipse, how to let revision annotation to ignore whitespace changes?

Tags: eclipse, cvs, annotations

In Eclipse, one can use Team -> Show Annotation to see the revision history at the side of editor window; My question is how to let such annotation to ignore whitespace changes?

[EDIT] This issue occurs to files containing any programming language, even text file containing English.

Comment: Which language are you programming in?

Comment: This issue occurred for files containing codes of any language. For example C++, if it makes the question better defined.

Comment: Does [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/354853/how-do-you-get-eclipses-built-in-diff-tool-to-ignore-differences-in-whitespace) help?

Answer (score 2):

A vanilla Eclipse editor, as far as I know, will always show a change annotation, even if it's whitespace (you can only change the colours in which changes are displayed under *General* > *Editors* > *Text Editors* > *Quick Diff*). If you're talking about the compare editor, then you can simply right-click and check the "Ignore White Space" option.

To override this, you'd have to write your own plugin (in which case you might want to start by looking at the interface [IQuickDiffReferenceProvider](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/texteditor/quickdiff/IQuickDiffReferenceProvider.html)).

Answer (score 0):

After this bug is fixed it works: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=379680

Answer (score 0):

This has to be implemented by the team provider.

For Git, there is a setting in **Preferences** > **Version Control (Team)** > **Git** > **Revision Information** > **Ignore whitespace changes** that is off by default.